# Alimentar Select com outro Select Mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estou tentando alimentar um `Select` de acordo com que foi selecionado em outro `Select` principal

```
<select id="grupo" name="grupo"  >
  <option>Selecionar Grupo</option>
    <?php if(isset($grupo->db->data[0])): ?>
      <?php foreach ($grupo->db->data as $grp) : ?>
        <option value="<?= $grp->grupo_id ?>"><?= $grp->grupo_nome ?>/option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</select>
```

Select Secundário

```
<select name="empresa" id="empresa">
</select>
```

Estou tentando alimentar com *JS*:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#grupo').on("change", function() {
    var id = $('select[name=grupo]').val();
    $('#grupo_id').val(id);
    var url = "empresa_fn.php?acao=Json";
    $.getJSON(url, {grupo_id: id}, function (data) {
        // não estou conseguindo atribuir o valores para os options 
        // do select
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exitem várias maneiras de você fazer.

A mais prática é usar o `$.each` do JQuery

> Tendo como retorno o JSON de exemplo: [{"id":"1", "value":"Exemplo 1"},{"id":"2","value":"Exemplo 2"}]

```
$.getJSON(url, {grupo_id: id}, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        $('#empresa').append($('<option>', { 
            value: item.id,
            text : item.value 
        }));
    });
}
```

Também existe a possibilidade de você criar uma função:

```
function populate(selector,json_values) {

  for(var i = 0; i < json_values.length; i++) {
     var obj = json[i];
     $(selector).append('<option value="'+json[i].id+'">'+json[i].value+'</option>')
  }
}

populate('#empresa',data);
```

Uma prática bem comum é antes de você começar a criar as novas opções é interessante limpar o `select` utilizando o `.empty()` ( `$("#empresa").empty()` ) , isso fará que o campo fique limpo para a entrada de novos dados.